# How to locate current location marker in android studio?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am creating an app in Android studio that uses Google map services. When I run the app I cannot locate my current location marker. I am trying to use local location broadcasting from location service that has the current location class to my map fragment. Please help me know where the issue is because I am new in creating Android Apps.

```
<receiver android:name=".Fragments.HomeFragment"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="location-update" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

androidManifest.xml code

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

    }
    private BroadcastReceiver locationUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("location-update", "Received location update broadcast");
            double newLatitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0);
            double newLongitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0);
            // update the marker with new location
            updateMarker(newLatitude, newLongitude);
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Register the locationUpdateReceiver to listen for location updates
//        Log.d("location-update", "Received location update broadcast");
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("location-update");
        requireActivity().registerReceiver(locationUpdateReceiver, filter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Unregister the locationUpdateReceiver when the fragment is paused
        requireActivity().unregisterReceiver(locationUpdateReceiver);
    }
    private void updateMarker(double newLatitude, double newLongitude) {
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(newLatitude, newLongitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(newLocation)
                    .title("Your location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLocation, 17));
        }
    }
```

HomeFragment class

```
private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null) {
                double latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                double longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();

                sendLocationUpdateBroadcast(latitude, longitude);
};
private void sendLocationUpdateBroadcast(double latitude, double longitude){
        Intent intent = new Intent("location-update");
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), "com.example.registration.Fragments.HomeFragment"));
        intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
        intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
//        Log.d("Location_update", latitude + ". " + longitude);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
```

LocationService class

Comment: Have you followed this guide on the official documentation?  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial